# @Query return Page of Object instead Page of Entity Object

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I was having a problem with Spring Data, I've a ReserveRepository that extends PagingAndSortingRepository<>, and this interface has this query annotation with an inner join:

```
@Query("SELECT r.id, r.name, r.description, i FROM Reserve r INNER JOIN r.image i")
Page<Reserve> findWithoutAnimal(Pageable pageable);
```

But when I call this method, instead of return a Page like the method signature, it returns a Page.

Why is that happening?

I've solved this issue by creating an customized constructor on my model and changing the JPQL to use that constructor, like this example:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.package.thepackage.model.Reserve(r.id, r.name, r.description, r.image) FROM Reserve r")
```

But there's another solution to that?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `Reserve` an entity (`@Entity`) class? Try this `@Query("SELECT r FROM Reserve r  JOIN FETCH r.image i")`

Comment: It worked bringing the Reserve with image, but there's another relationship (Reserve - Animal) that I don't want to fill, and with this query Animal was filled.

I've tried @Query("SELECT r.id, r.name, r.description, i FROM Reserve r JOIN FETCH r.image i") but throws an error